# Push method in useState hook || REACT NATIVE

Tags: react-native

I have an array of items in a state variable like this.

```javascript
const [items, setItems] = useState(["item1", "item2", "item3")])
```

How to replace one item in the array. Below is the method I have used to get it done.

```javascript
{
    let dummy = [...items]
    dummy[1] = "items 1.1"
    setItems(dummy)
}
```

But, I am thinking that this is not at all the right way to do this.

Is there any other simplified way to solve this? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is not wrong, but I would add an extra check to make sure that `items` array contains an element which you wish to change.

```js
let dummy = [...items]

if(typeof dummy[1] == 'undefined') {
    // does not exist
}
else {
    // does exist
    dummy[1] = "items 1.1"
}
setItems(dummy)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use `slice`

```
const idxToChange = 1
setItems([items.slice(0, idxToChange), "items 1.1", items.slice(idxToChange+1, items.length)])
```

A good explanation of `slice`
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp

Answer (score 0):

Heres another way to do it. I don't know it's cleaner for you or not.

```
 setItems(items=> items.map((item,idx)=> idx===1?"items 1.1":item));
```